# Работа с заархивированными файлами в Android

Tags: android, java

Необходимо разархивировать запароленный архив вложенный в ресурсы приложения. Подскажите каким образом это можно сделать?

***UPDATE***: Не в том ключе был понят вопрос. В целях защиты информации было решено хранить часть ресурсов(видео) в запароленном архиве. Но встала проблема разархивирования содержимого на лету и его воспроизведения.

1. правилен ли данный подход?
2. есть ли какие-то альтернативы? (было использовано шифрование, но оно заняло довольно долгое время)
3. каким образом можно распаковать зашифрованный архив (есть ли биб-ка или какой-либо пример)?

Comment: андроид причем тут? брутфорсом попробуй...

Comment: > есть ли какие-то альтернативы? (было
> использовано шифрование, но оно заняло
> довольно долгое время)

обычно видео стараются передавать с сервера, например как на юТюбе

как зашифровано она? в каком формате? может вы свои кодеки написали?))

Answer (score 1):

Переименуйте APK  в ZIP вытащите из каталога res/ запароленный архив и начинайте его курочить обычными средствами - слава богу средств курочить силами [brute-force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack) (грубая сила) много.

Comment: грубая сила =) грубый перевод, лучше как - полный перебор =)